# Posicionamento de divs

Tags: html, css

Estou com um problema a posicionar os divs dos produtos eles não ficam alinhados.

http://casimirowebshare.000webhostapp.com/nutrirossio/produtos.php

Como podem ver aqui no CSS tenho:

```
.produto_em_destaque{
     display: table;
     width: 70%;
     float: right;}

.produtos_em_destaque{
     display: inline-table;
     width: 20%;
     height: 283px;
     text-align: center;
    }
```

No HTML tenho:

```
<div id="produto_em_destaque" class="produto_em_destaque">
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<div class="produtos_em_destaque">
 <a href=<?php echo "produto.php?id=" . $row['id']; ?>>
 <img class="produtos_em_destaque_img" src=<?php echo "imagens/" . $row['imagem'] ?>>
<h4><?php echo $row['nome'] ?></h4>
<span><?php echo $row['preco'] ?>€</span>
</a>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: As imagens que você coloca de cada produto estão com tamanhos padronizados?, perceba que na ultima linha que as imagens são todas iguais (de mesma altura), não acontece o problema citado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu caso, com o uso da propriedade CSS ***vertical-align*** setando o valor ***top*** pode resolver. Mas tavez você tenha que repensar a maneira que está fazendo a compatibilidade mobile.

Comment: é isso obrigado :D